# Kubernetes Ingress cannot access with Windows Machine - AWS

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a `Kubeadm` cluster (1 node) running on an `AWS` EC2 instance and I have done the followings;

1. Install Cilium

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/projectcalico/calico/v3.26.1/manifests/calico.yaml -O
kubectl apply -f calico.yaml
```

2. Install Metal-LB and set IP range (internal)

```
kubectl edit configmap -n kube-system kube-proxy


// and set 
apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: KubeProxyConfiguration
mode: "ipvs"
ipvs:
  strictARP: true

// then install Metal LB
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/metallb/metallb/v0.13.10/config/manifests/metallb-native.yaml


// Set IPAddressPool
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: IPAddressPool
metadata:
  name: first-pool
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  addresses:
  - 172.31.88.0/21 # <-- Since my EC2 in the Subnet `172.31.80.0/20`

// Set L2Advertisement
apiVersion: metallb.io/v1beta1
kind: L2Advertisement
metadata:
  name: example
  namespace: metallb-system
spec:
  ipAddressPools:
  - first-pool
```

3. Install Helm and then install Nginx Ingress Controller

```
helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx \
  --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx \
  --namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace
```

4. Deploy the application

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
  
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  ingressClassName: "nginx"
  rules:
    - host: nginx.jananathbanuka.site
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: nginx
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Once it is deployed, I have an IP for the above ingress as below;

```
kubectl get ing 

NAME            CLASS   HOSTS                       ADDRESS       PORTS   AGE
nginx-ingress   nginx   nginx.jananathbanuka.site   172.31.88.0   80      16m
```

And I have a windows machine **but in a different subnet but in the same vpc**. And I have added the entry `172.31.88.0 nginx.jananathbanuka.site` at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

But I still can't reach the nginx server when I try to access the site `https://nginx.jananathbanuka.site` from the windows machine. But I can still access it with the Linux EC2 install with `curl -kv https://nginx.jananathbanuka.site`

Both Linux EC2 and the windows machines use the same security group and I have allowed all the traffic within the same security group.

Can someone help me what I have doing wrong here?